# FireFox "XML Parsing Error" with Hello World WebSite!

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iis-6

I get the following problem when trying to open an ASPX page in FireFox:

"XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost/FrameworkTest2/Default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:"

This site works fine in IE.

To get to the root of the problem, I removed all code and built a "Hello World" page instead.

This works in IE, but I still get the problem in FF!

I'm using FF 3.0.11 and IIS 6 on Vista.

Not expecting an answer here (unless I'm lucky) but I'm out of ideas.  It's defo in the IIS ASP.NET processing pipeline, as .htm files render okay.

Even if you could give me some things to check that would be great!

Cheers
Duncan

Comment: What's the source of the response? CTRL+U in FireFox. Also, knowing the HTTP response headers would help.

Comment: There is no source!  It's bizarre.  How would I quickly find out the HTTP response header?

Comment: Just tried it on Safari and it's fine.  I suspect a dodgy FireFox add-on, but I've tried it in safe-mode and that still doesn't sort it.

Comment: You could install the HttpFox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647. Or LiveHTTPHeaders: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829

Comment: Nice, I get an 403 Forbidden on the Response Header.  But still, why would only FF have a problem with this??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, found out it was actually due to a proxy server setting that had been set up by our IT department, so it couldn't resolve localhost.

Really bizarre problem, I know this isn't the best question in the world so if pressured I'll pull it - but might be useful to someone else in future, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem resolved by changing address from localhost to blank address under endpoint. Example address="http://localhsot/IISHostedService/MyService.svc" to address=""

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error in your web.config file.

Comment: If that was the case, why would it be okay on Safari and IE?

Comment: You're right. I had this error in the past and I think it was due to a problem in a config file (but I can't remember exactly).